# How to make sharepoint 2010 foundation global navigation font-size bigger (customize look and feel)

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint 2010 foundation, I'm trying to get a better look and feel for the global navigation, to be more specific, I need the navigation bar bigger.

Currently I'm using a copy of v4.master, with drop-down function added, nothing else changed.

I tried to modify the "_themes/28/COREV4-8A0ABD2F.CSS" file (I didn't see any core.css file but this one), however, whatever I do to this file, my SharePoint site refuse to react.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes the font size bigger might impact other elements of the menu and the page.

So probably ... some example code of a css file you can insert as a reference to in your master page copy would be handy (and that css file might very well sit in a library on your site).

Take a look at this CSS: http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2/ for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for help! It seems I'm having some trouble with my net and I cannot open the link.. I will take a look later. btw I'm quite confused that nothing happens when I modify the "_themes/28/COREV4-8A0ABD2F.CSS" file. Any idea with that? Thanks again

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668169/sharepoint-2010-corev4-css-changes-not-reflecting-on-subsites

Comment: Thanks a lot, also sorry for getting back to you this late